# autorun script for batch transfer

Tags: batch-file

I am not a programmer in the least. I read through a few posts before asking to see if any would apply to my seemingly simple question. Unfortunately I did not find any that explained what I am looking for.

My question is:
I want to be able to send a USB stick to my Mom every month filled with pictures. She is not computer savvy in the least. 
I would like for the process to be simple and duplicate-able for other members of my family also.
On my Mom's computer I made a directory C:\Family Pictures. That is where all the pictures are that she can open easily to see them.
Each month I'd like to send her more pictures(Lot's of them). I would like to put them all on a USB and when she plugs it in they will automatically transfer from usb to designated folder on drive C mentioned above.

We both use Windows 10 and it is my understanding that my 6 brothers & Sisters are as well. This way all of my family can send her USBs every month.

Is this even possible? I would love to learn how to create this there by making it simple for Mom :)
Thanks in Advance,
Me

Comment: Last time I checked Autorun for USB devices was disabled since Windows 7.

Comment: So does that mean it is not possible?

Comment: Nice question, I am curious about the answer. Was about to down-vote just because no code samples etc. But the question is just fine in it's simple state.

Comment: I understand YoYo but I am not a " programmer" just a dude interested in making my Mom's life a little happier :)

Comment: You could install a cloud sync service such as dropbox, mega, sync.com, etc... on every computer. Would be much less troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Autorun is no longer available since Windows 7, so you can place a batch file in the desktop and tell her to insert the USB drive and then run the desktop script in sequence.

The code would be something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:=============================================================
:OPTIONS - you can change these values

set _SourcePath=C:\Family Pictures
set _DestPath=X:\Family Pictures\Mama

:=============================================================
set _LogPath=%_DestPath%\_log.txt

echo/
echo/This will copy the family files:
echo/ FROM: %_SourcePath% 
echo/ TO: %_DestPath%
echo/

:prompt1
  set /p msgbox=Continue? [Y/N]
  if /i "%msgbox%"=="n" (echo/"Aborted..." &goto:end)
  if /i "%msgbox%"=="y" goto:step1
goto:prompt1

:step1
  if exist "%_DestPath%\" goto:step2
  echo/
  echo Folder %_DestPath% does not exist.
  echo/
  :prompt2
    set /p msgbox=Create folder? [Y/N]
    if /i "%msgbox%"=="n" (echo/"Aborted..." &goto:end)
    if /i "%msgbox%"=="y" goto:CreateFolder
  goto:prompt2

:CreateFolder
  md "%_DestPath%"
  echo %errorlevel%
  if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo/Aborting: error while creating destination folder &goto:end)

:step2
  echo/
  echo/ Copying files...
  echo/
  xcopy "%_SourcePath%" "%_DestPath%" /Z /Y /E > "%_LogPath%"
  if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 goto:DeleteLog
  :prompt3
    set /p msgbox=There were errors copying the files. View log file? [Y/N]
    if /i "%msgbox%"=="n" goto:DeleteLog
    if /i "%msgbox%"=="y" (notepad "%_LogPath%" &goto:end)
  goto:prompt3

:DeleteLog
  del "%_LogPath%"

:end
endlocal
```

NOTES:

- Change the paths under :OPTIONS to the desired paths